# 'deserializing' JSON to sqlalchemy model

Tags: web-scraping, serialization, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy, deserialization

I'm storing some RESTful api calls into a relational database using sqlalchemy, and I'm looking for a way to 'deserialize' or pythonify some or all of the incoming fields, for instance I might have a json object like

```json
{
  'id': 1,
  'created_at': '2021-05-27T03:22:38Z',
  'count': '3'
}
```

and I would like a way to "automatically" deserialize the data, similar to how djangorestframework serializers work where fields like "created_at" could be defined as datetime fields, and you could optionally cast 'count' as an integer, and run something like

```
...setup

# get the json from before as a dict 
item = client.get_item()

# somehow serialize here
session = Session()
item_model = Item(**item_data[0])
session.add(item_model)
session.commit()
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: So you're not using DRF/Django but Flask/FlaskRestX+SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: I'm actually not even using flask, I'm just using sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple well knowns module to perform serialization (independant of any framework):

Marshmallow: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Typesystem (by the creator of DRF): https://github.com/encode/typesystem

You can also do your own serializer, based on DRF serializer code, if your use case is simple, or just perform a lookup of your dict fields that perform validation/transformation.